# i need to set the priority of image always on top of text when using @media, what attribute should i use?

Tags: html, css

[resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWzB.jpg)

when resizing the window i need the image to appear on top of the text  but when using a bigger resolution i need it to appear just as the attached image, find below my css:

```
.section4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

}

.section4 #title {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.section4 #text {
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML is really hard to decipher what you are doing wrong but here is an example you can use and all you have to do is tweak your class names

HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="card row img-left">
    <div class="column-1-2">
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-2">
      <p>
        Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla
        sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla porttitor
        accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.
        Proin eget tortor risus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card row img-right">
    <div class="column-1-2">
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-2">
      <p>
        Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla
        sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla porttitor
        accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.
        Proin eget tortor risus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  body {
    background: #cccccc;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .column-1-2 {
    width: 48%;
    padding: 1%;
  }

  .card {
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .card.img-right {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .card p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .card img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .row {
      align-items: column;
    }
    .column-1-2 {
      width: 98%;
      padding: 1%;
    }
  }
```

Here's a [**sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wave-yjzsz?file=/index.html) for ya

NOTE* If you have or use an HTML framework you could do this a lot simpler. UKGrid has an exact example of this